# goclipse go binary location on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, go, goclipse

I'm using Go 1.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, installed through the package manager. Output of go env

```
GOARCH="386"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="8"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/mel/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m32 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

I can compile and run the hello world example from the command line, but GoClipse, with GOROOT set to /usr/lib/go gives me the following error:

```
GOROOT: `/usr/lib/go/bin/go` executable not found.
```

The go binary is in /usr/bin/go, not $GOPATH/bin/go. How can I tell GoClipse this?

thank you!

Comment: Update to a recent version of go (currently 1.5.1) following the [official installation instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install) , and don't set GOROOT.

Comment: this method seems a lot less confusing to goclipse, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

per comment from @JimB, worked when using go install files from the official site, not the package manager version which is out of date and puts things in places goclipse doesn't expext